# Spring redirect not working, only showing redirect:/url in browser

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, redirect

I thought I had this piece of code working a few days ago, but now I can't seem to figure it out and I have no idea why it isn't working. I have this method which will handle requests only if the cacheRefreshIsEnabled parameter is present:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/features", method = RequestMethod.GET, params = {"cacheRefreshIsEnabled"})
    public @ResponseBody 
    String getSetting(@RequestParam(value="cacheRefreshIsEnabled", required=true) boolean cacheRefreshIsEnabled) { 
        // do some stuff
        return "redirect:features"
    }
```

and another method which looks like:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/features", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody 
    // etc...
```

but at the end of my first method, the redirect isn't changing the URL at all. Instead, "redirect:features" is shown in my browser window.

What am I doing wrong? Is there some config file I need to modify? I am very new to Spring.

[SOLUTION]

I changed my code around and got it working. Thank you for your help! Here is what I've got now:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/features", method = RequestMethod.GET, params ={"cacheRefreshIsEnabled"})
    String getSetting(@RequestParam(value="cacheRefreshIsEnabled", required=true) boolean cacheRefreshIsEnabled) { 
        // do some stuff
        return "redirect:/features"
    }
```

Comment: why you use `@ResponseBody` if that response is not AJAX based at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at the purpose of `@ResponseBody`. Problem is due to `@ResponseBody` anotation which is showing the content as is. The annotation is used when one wants to pass the content as Ajax response. removing the `@ResponseBody` will solve the purpose.

Comment: That did it for me, I will update my question. Thanks.

Comment: It didn't work for me even without @ResponseBody annotation. Any ideas?

Comment: @endless What's the actual problem being faced by you?